# Efficient Kullback–Leibler calculation

Tags: c++, performance, math

I am looking to implement KL Divergence in C++ efficiently. (CPU Only for now).

Much like AES or FTT (Fast Fourier transform) whereby use of a common function has lead to hardware level optimizations ([Intel AES](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/doc/white-paper/advanced-encryption-standard-new-instructions-set-paper.pdf) and [Intel FTT](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/tools/math-kernel-library/fast-fourier-transforms.html)).
Is there anything similar for natural log, or slightly higher level efficiencies (ASM/C) that prevent bottlenecks of executing many Natural log functions in success (If they exist)?

Same use case examples:

```
.Many parallel and independent node executions; each one performing 20~ KL calculations from localized (not shared or pointer reffed) memory.

.Scheduled KL: executing in stepped-parallel where the hardware is setup expecting uses of for example tables (assuming tables are used at this lower level - AES implement ions indicated this is a high probability) .
```

I have found a possible candiate, but I'm unsure: [ALTFP_LOG](https://www.intel.co.jp/content/dam/altera-www/global/ja_JP/pdfs/literature/ug/ug_altfp_log.pdf)

Comment: How accurate do you want the log to be? There is an accuracy/speed tradeoff, especially if you manually implement log with SSE/AVX intrinsics

Comment: I only need to about 6dp. Not requiring Double precision at all.
The KL will be used to estimate the stability of a difference between signals. The idea being if the value reaches a min/max the resolution required could be adjusted perhaps (U shapes curve with frequency of use).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`SSE instructions`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=log&cats=Elementary%20Math%20Functions) to calculate the logarithm of many values in parallel. But whether you can actually make use of those instructions depends heavily on how the rest of the calculations you are going to do depend on the logarithms you calculate, so it is not possible to give a more specific answer.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I will try and add examples to the original question, I will accept your answer if there isn't an exception.

Comment: I accepted this answer after further investigation.
Most notably: http://gruntthepeon.free.fr/ssemath/

Comment: Due to the pre-calculations required for me to execute the KL equation, I've left it as inline, however the bulk operations exist in a thread, so the need to speed up this calc is for later..